# Using a Shared SSJS functions in my Automation Script Activity

Tags: marketing-cloud, ssjs, automationstudio

Let me preface this by saying that I am not looking at cloud pages. I am looking to either use `Content Blocks` or other `Activity Scripts` to store JS functions which I can load into an Automation Script Activity when needed; just as if I was using `Require` in JS to load another file. Prior to creating this question; I reviewed two different posts on similar use cases but not quite the same.

- [Accessing SSJS variables and functions from a Content Block](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/301559/accessing-ssjs-variables-and-functions-from-a-content-block)
- [Using Shared Content Blocks (Code Snippet - SSJS) and calling that Content Block inside an SSJS script](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/357568/using-shared-content-blocks-code-snippet-ssjs-and-calling-that-content-block)

**Sample Script Activity (Automation Studio)**

```
<script runat="server" language="javascript">
  Platform.Load("Core", "1.1.1");

  var environment = "test";

  var contentBlockKey = environment + "_" + "GetFirstName" + ".js";
  Platform.Function.ContentBlockByKey(contentBlockKey);

  var contentBlockKey = environment + "_" + "GetLastName" + ".js";
  Platform.Function.ContentBlockByKey(contentBlockKey);

  var contentBlockKey = environment + "_" + "GetFullName" + ".js";
  Platform.Function.ContentBlockByKey(contentBlockKey);
  
  var de = DataExtension.Init("MyLog");
  var result = fullname("john", "doe");
  de.Rows.Add({message: result});
</script>
```

**Sample Code Snippet (Email Studio)**

- **Name**: `test_GetFirstName.js`
- **Customer Key**: `test_GetFirstName.js`

```
<script runat="server" language="javascript">
  Platform.Load("Core", "1.1.1");

  function firstname(name) {
    /* do stuff */
    return name;
  }
</script>
```

**Sample Code Snippet (Email Studio)**

- **Name**: `test_GetLastName.js`
- **Customer Key**: `test_GetLastName.js`

```
<script runat="server" language="javascript">
  Platform.Load("Core", "1.1.1");

  function lastname(name) {
    /* do stuff */
    return name;
  }
</script>
```

**Sample Code Snippet (Email Studio)**

- **Name**: `test_GetFullName.js`
- **Customer Key**: `test_GetFullName.js`

```
<script runat="server" language="javascript">
  Platform.Load("Core", "1.1.1");

  function fullname(a, b) {
    /* do stuff */
    return firstname(a) + " " + lastname(b);
  }
</script>
```

**The Problem**: This way of trying to share functions so that they can be used across different Script Activities doesn't work. Even if I move the `ContentBlockByKey` calls to the top of the Script Activity with their own `<script runat="server"></script>` tags, it still doesn't work. In particular I can't carry the environment variable between `script` tags/blocks.

I've written universal/sharable functions such as:

- `GetDataExtensionExternalKeyByName(name)`
- `GetAutomationExternalKeyByName(name)`
- `GetAutomationHistory(key)`

However, I am NOT able to figure out how to share them. Ideally, I want them in:

1. Grouped in Code Snippets (Email Studio) and/or separate Code Snippets depending on the use case. For example; All automation-related functions would be in one code snippet, while all data extension related functions would be in another.
2. Alternatively; I would love to just be able to store the code in different script activities and use `Require` or something to load them.

Any feedback or guidance is appreciated. Thank you.

**Additional Issue**; `WSProxy` declaration must be in the parent script and cannot be declared and initialized in a function.

Comment: Do you know of he SSJS Lib? You could probably look how it's structured and imported and adapt it the loading method to your needs. You will find it here: https://github.com/email360/ssjs-lib

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion but I can't use Cloud Pages; they aren't accessible to me.